# How do I use a column value in a substrings where clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

03-30 13:17]

I'm trying to use a t-sql against SQL-Server 2005 with asp 3.0. What I want to do is first select all rows that match a certain condition and then I want to know how how many children are connected to that row based on it's ChildID.

This can of course be done by just doing two queries against the db one to get the matching rows for the Parent and one for each row that was found to know how many children have that as Parent.

I have two tables, table1 contains parents and children and table2 contains the information and the id here is ofcourse the id that is saved in parent and children in table1.

Now I want to first find all the children to a certain parent, and in the same sql-statement I want to know how many children is connected to each child.

So Parent 807 has two children, 808 and 809. 808 has 5 children and 809 has 72 children, how can I with one statement get both the information of children 808 and 809 and the numer of children connected to each of them.

My SQL looks like this (gets the children to parent 807)

`SELECT Parent, Child, ID, FieldX, FieldY

FROM Tabel1 INNER JOIN Tabel2 ON Parent = ID

WHERE (Parent = 807)`

The statement I use to get the numer of children connected to f.ex. 808 is as follows.

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS AntalPoster
FROM  Tabel1 INNER JOIN  Tabel2 ON Child = ID

WHERE     (Parent = 808)`

What I would like to do is the following, but I would like to substitute the value 808 with the value each record gives me for the child aka SearchID.

`SELECT Parent, Child AS SearchID, ID, FieldX, FieldY,

    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Antal sidor]

    FROM Tabel1 INNER JOIN Tabel2 ON Child = ID

    WHERE (Parent = 808)) AS AntalPoster

FROM  Tabel1 INNER JOIN Tabel2 ON Child = ID
WHERE     (Parent = 807)`

The problem I get is that "Invalid column name 'SearchID'", what I can understand is that I can't get the value that I find in SerachID to be used as a value in the next SQL-statements where clause.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to post the structures of your tables. It is really hard to understand what a parent is and what `ChildID`, `ID`, `Child`, `Parent` and `ParentID` belongs to and the relationship between them.

Comment: First rewrite your selects, using (different) table aliases both in inner and outer selects and for fields - maks query much readable and probably you can then see, how you can accomplish your task (hint: where inner.parent = outer.child).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I want to first find all the children to a certain parent, and in the same sql-statement I want to know how many children is connected to each child.

This is a way to do that.

```
declare @Table1 table (Table1ID int, ParentID int)

-- Root
insert into @Table1 values(807, null)

-- Children to 807
insert into @Table1 values(808, 807)
insert into @Table1 values(809, 807)

-- Children to 808
insert into @Table1 values(810, 808)

-- Children to 809
insert into @Table1 values(811, 809)
insert into @Table1 values(812, 809)

select
  T1.*,
  (select count(*)
   from @Table1 as T2
   where T1.Table1ID = T2.ParentID) as ChildCount
from @Table1 as T1
where T1.ParentID = 807
```

Result

```
Table1ID    ParentID    ChildCount
----------- ----------- -----------
808         807         1
809         807         2
```

Comment: This looks really promising, will try to do that tomorrow when I'm back at work.

Comment: Worked like a charm, had to do a slight change with a join since I didn't get data from T2 but with that change it lowered the calls to the database and made the query about 10 times faster, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

So, I understand, basically `Table1` contains hierarchy information, and `Table2` details.

Assuming that, here's my approach:

```
SELECT
  h.Parent,
  h.ChCount,
  d.*  /* you may want to expand it to a specific Table2 column list */
FROM (
  /* first, get the children and their child counts */
  SELECT
    p.Parent,
    p.Child,
    COUNT(*) AS ChCount
  FROM Table1 p
    INNER JOIN Table1 c ON p.Child = c.Parent
  GROUP BY p.Parent, p.Child
  WHERE p.Parent = 807
) h
  /* next, get the children's details */
  INNER JOIN Table2 d ON h.Child = d.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
WHERE (Parent = SearchID))
```

by

```
WHERE (Parent = ParentID))
```

But you're better of using

```
SELECT Parent, Child, ID, FieldX, FieldY, COUNT(*) AS AntalPoster 
  FROM Tabel1 INNER JOIN Tabel2 ON Child = ID 
 WHERE (Parent = [ParentID]) 
 GROUP 
    BY Parent, Child, ID, FieldX, FieldY;
```

Comment: That gives me the number of posts the parentpage has, but I want to know how many posts the childpage has.

F.ex. ParentID 807 has 2 children, ChildPage 808 and ChildPage 809.
ParentPage 809 (same as Childpage but now as Parent) has 72 children.

What I want to show is ID 808 (5 children) ID 809 (72 children). With the above sql-statement I just get ID 808 (2 children) ID 809 (2 children) which is the number of children 807 has.  

Hope that clarifies it better.

Comment: I think you just have to change the join clause, but posting the table structures and some data would be clearer

Answer (score 0):

If you define a "alias" for a column you can't use this name inside the query earlier than within a  `group by` or `order by` clause.

As is your example `SearchID` is just a name for column `Child`
 you should use `WHERE (PARENT = Child)`

Comment: I probably didn't desribe my problem good and what I wanted out of it. But if I change it to WHERE (PARENT = Child), I get 0 as value for AntalPoster.

Answer (score 0):

You're kinda close.

```
 SELECT Parent_ID, COUNT(*) AS AntalPoster FROM Tabel1 INNER JOIN Tabel2 ON Child = ID
 Group by Parent_ID
```

Now I don' quite understand from reading your question what the 'ID' field is called...but the results of this query should give the Parent_ID along with the count of the number of child records (If I've read your setup corectly).  Join to that subquerty to get the count.

```
SELECT Parent, Child.AntalPoster, ID, FieldX, FieldY
FROM Tabel1 INNER JOIN Tabel2 ON Parent = ID
inner join (SELECT Parent_ID, COUNT(*) AS AntalPoster FROM Tabel1 INNER JOIN Tabel2 ON Child = ID  Group by Parent_ID) child on child.id = t1.ID
WHERE (Parent = 807)
```

Whats really confusing me in your example...if I'm still off with what you're going for...quickly giving us the schema would help.   Is the table setup so it has  Parent, Child, ID?   If so, how does the work?  I'd expect Parent_ID, Child_ID...bit confused on the third "ID" column, what does it hold thats unique from the parent,child columns that already exist?.

In any case, the logic is setup a subquery so it reads  Key , Count(1).  Then join to that subquery on the Key to obtain the count value the subquery returns.

Comment: My problem is that I know the value 807 but i don't know the value 808 at the time i send the statement, I would like to get the ID 808 out from the first sql statement and from that use that in the statement to get the numbers of children connected. I can do that simply by just making another call to the database, but that is a lot of extra roundtrips to the database, What I would like to do is to just go there once, get all the data and close of the connection. Is that possible?

Comment: Ah, sorry..I did partially miss the question.   I'm editting my answer for you.